why the map $X \mapsto X^2$ induces a $K$-monomorphism?
Suppose that $L: K $is finite and  every $K-$monomorphism $L \to L$ is an  automorphism. Does this result hold if the extension is not finite?
I found the answer here
It written that

It is necessary that the extension be finite.
Consider $L=K(X)$, the field of rational functions over $K$.


The map $X \mapsto X^2$ induces a $K$-monomorphism $K(X) \to K(X)$ which is not subjective

My attempt : Define  $\varphi : K[X] \to K[X]$  by $\varphi(x)=x^2$
Here $\varphi$ is not surjective because   the polynomial $g(x)=x$ is not in the image of $\varphi$
It is not clear to me why the map $X \mapsto X^2$ induces a $K$-monomorphism $K(X) \to K(X)$
I know that if  $\varphi$  induces a  $K$-monomorphism then  $\varphi$  must be injective
According to me $ \varphi$ is not injective  because  $\varphi(x)=\varphi(-x)=x^2$

The map is supposed to send $-X$ to $-X^2$. For example, $\varphi(2+2X^2+4X^3) = 2 + 2X^4 + 4X^6$.

@Amateur_Algebraist Are you saying $ \varphi(-x)=-\varphi(x)$.Am i right ?

According to the universal property of polynomial rings, there exists a unique homomorphism $\varphi$ from $K[X]$ to $K(X)$ that extends the embedding $K\hookrightarrow K(X)$ and sends $X$ to $X^2$. In fact $\varphi(p(X))=p(X^2)$ for all polynomials $p\in K[X]$.
We know $\varphi$ is injective, because if $p(X)\in \ker(\varphi)$, then $\varphi(p(X))=p(X^2)=0$, so $p=0$.
According to the universal property of fraction field, the above homomorphism from $K[X]$ to $K(X)$ can be uniquely extended to be a homomorphism from $\operatorname{Frac}(K[X])=K(X)$ to $K(X)$. We still call the extension $\varphi$.
$\varphi$ is still injective, because $\ker\varphi$ is a proper ideal of $K(X)$ but $K(X)$ is a field which has only one proper ideal $\{0\}$.
This is a rather abstract argument. Alternatively, you can just verify that $\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}\mapsto \frac{p(X^2)}{q(X^2)}$ is a homomorphism from the field $K(X)$ to itself.
